# Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am getting this error whenever I try to make build using angular ssr.

I upgraded Angular 12.0.1 to 13.2. After this I had error saying

`IDBIndex is not defined`

To sovled this I follwed this repo from [Firebase](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/universal/getting-started.md#3-add-a-webpack-config-for-the-express-server) also got help by creating [custom webpack config js file](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2475#issuecomment-1002451877)

After completing those steps now I am facing this issue during ssr bundle generation. I have no clue what is this error saying.

```
✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names                     | Raw Size
main.js             | main                      |  3.03 MB | 
server.js           | server                    |  3.03 MB | 

                    | Initial Total             |  6.06 MB

Lazy Chunk Files    | Names                     | Raw Size
59.js               | utils-multipart-parser-js | 13.24 kB | 

Build at: 2022-01-27T17:59:26.906Z - Hash: 606174cd0faf82ba - Time: 1431ms

./node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2015/browser.mjs - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/http.mjs - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.mjs - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm2015/init.mjs - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/data-uri-to-buffer/dist/index.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/fetch-blob/file.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/fetch-blob/from.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/fetch-blob/index.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/formdata-polyfill/esm.min.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/node-fetch/src/body.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/node-fetch/src/errors/abort-error.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency

./node_modules/node-fetch/src/errors/fetch-error.js - Error: No template for dependency: PureExpressionDependency
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "13.2.0",

    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "crypto-js": "4.0.0",
    "data-uri-to-buffer": "^4.0.0",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "fetch-blob": "^3.1.4",
    "filestack-js": "^3.23.1",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^4.0.10",
    "highlight.js": "10.7.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.9",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.20",
    "ng-stripe-checkout": "^1.0.4",
    "ng-wistia-components": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.0",
    "rrule": "2.6.8",
    "rxjs": "7.5.2",
    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^12.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^13.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@ngx-builders/analyze": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "4.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/highlight.js": "9.12.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.4",
    "@types/node": "15.0.1",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "ws": "^8.2.2",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.1"
  }
```

---

[Got response from maintainer](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2475#issuecomment-1054624298)

### AngularFire maintainer here, the root cause appears to be Firebase JS SDK's usage of the idb library. The version of the library that it uses doesn't have exports in its package.json and expects CJS to be loaded in Node.js. In Angular 13.1+ (unsure exactly which minor the change was introduced) that means unguarded calls to IndexDB are present in your server bundle, since it's now bundling ESM, and causing runtime exceptions on load...

Comment: delete `.angular' and `dist` folder and retry. They may contain older build fragments. In a NxMono repo, you can use `--skip-nx-cache` param in your npm scripts like `"build:my-app:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nx build my-app --skip-nx-cache`". Replace dev with prod, and set NODE_ENV to production for prod-envs.